# Adding exec /bin/bash to script to behave exactly like /bin/bash?

Tags: bash, docker, exec

I am trying to create a script that *looks* just like `/bin/bash`, but it is actually a shell script that executes bash internally as a different user.

Consider the following `user-bash.sh` file.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

USER_ID="$USER_ID"

if [ -z "$USER_ID" ]; then
    echo "Set USER_ID to 1000"
    USER_ID="1000"
fi

# Create the dummy user, if it doesn't exist.
id dummy > /dev/null 2>&1 || { 
    echo "Creating dummy user..."
    useradd -u ${USER_ID} dummy
    mkdir -p /home/dummy/.ssh
}

# Doesn't work, but I think it illustrates what I'm trying to do.
su dummy -c "/bin/bash"
```

I'd like for `user-bash.sh` to behave *exactly* like `/bin/bash`, including support for `stdin`/`stdout`, args and exit code.

How would I do this?

Some background, I'm trying to create an entry point script for a Docker image that always executes as another user. The default entry point for most images is `/bin/bash`. I'd like to make it `/bin/user-bash.sh`.

Comment: Maybe this package will work for me?

https://github.com/tianon/gosu

```exec gosu dummy /bin/bash "$@"```

Comment: Could you provide more information why creating and setting the execution user when you build the docker image does not fit your use case? (E.g. in the "Dockerfile"?)

Comment: Because the user id has to be dynamic. It has to match the user running the docker command so that the files generated in mounted directories would have proper permissions.

Using the USER in Dockerfile is for a hard-coded user built into the image.